# Odd behaviour from conditional statement?

Tags: python, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
dummy_list = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

if 1 in dummy_list is [0]:
    print ("it is the first element")
else:
    print ("no it is not the first element")
```

I am trying to check through a list, identify if a variable's position in the list is within a specified locale. Now, despite the fact that [0] IS 1, (i verified this by the following):

```
print (dummy_list[0])
```

Which returned 1; I am confused then as to why the conditional statement is stating otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is a separate test from `is`; you [chained the comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons), and Python executes the test as:

```
(1 in dummy_list) and (dummy_list is [0])
```

Both tests fail. There is no `1` integer in `dummy_list`, only a `"1"` string object. And `dummy_list` is not the exact same object as the list produced by the `[0]` expression; the latter will always produce a new list object so the [`is` identity test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) always fails.

You can't make an assertion about the `in` test; you can't test what index the containment matched. Just test the index *explicitly*:

```
if dummy_list[0] == "1":
```

or if `dummy_list` could be an empty list, add a test to make sure it is not empty:

```
if dummy_list and dummy_list[0] == "1":
```